# Calling a method in the ViewController from a subClass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I was wondering how I call a method in my ViewController from a subclass?

I tried to call this from the viewDidLoad of my subClass.m file, but xCode tells me that request for member 'viewController' in something not a structure or union:

```
[self.viewController tabAdd:@"Extra" inColour:@"Green" withReference:0];
[self.viewController resetTabsView];
```

In my viewController I defined the methods as follows:

```
-(void)tabAdd:(NSString *)newTabTitle inColour:(NSString *)newTabColour withReference:(NSUInteger)newTabReference;
-(void)resetTabsView;
```

Thanks for your help!

---

This is how I set up the VC and subclass...

(1) TabsEdit.H:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface TabsEdit : MyViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITextField *enterTitle;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *enterTitle;
@end
```

(2) MyViewController.H:

```
    //

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TabsEdit.h"

@class TabsEdit;

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {

// ...

//@property (nonatomic, retain) TabsEdit *tabsEdit;
```

in M. File:

```
@synthesize tabsEdit;
```

And the I init it like this:

```
TabsEdit *tEdit = [[TabsEdit alloc] initWithNibName:@"TabsEdit" bundle:nil];
self.tabsEdit = tEdit;
[self.view addSubview:tEdit.view];
[tEdit release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments above, you need your sub class to say what it is a sub class of. The first line of the interface should be:

```
@interface TabsEdit : MyViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
```

Then as @DavidNeiss said use [self tabAdd: ...] in the subclass.  A class can call all of its own methods and all of the methods belonging to its parent classes using "self".

Use "super" in cases where you have overridden a parent class's method with one of your own and you need to call the parent's method and not your own.  For example when you have a custom -(id)init for your subclass you should call[super init] in it somewhere to take care of any setup that the parent class does in its -(id)init.

Comment: If I do this, I get the error message: cannot find interface declaration for 'MyVieController', superclass of 'TabsEdit'...

Comment: make sure you include an #import "MyViewController.h" at the begining of the interface

Comment: still no luck... with #import ... I still get the same error message: cannot find interface declaration for 'MyViewController', superclass of 'TabsEdit'...

Comment: Okay, I think we may be having a terminology issue here. You should have these files: MyViewController.h, MyViewController.m, TabsEdit.h, TabsEdit.m, and in each of those .h files there should be the implementations shown above.

Comment: also, MyViewController should not have: @property (nonatomic, retain) TabsEdit* tabsedit;

Comment: (no offence intended if these are things you already have down) A "subclass" is a subtype of another "class" like a Ford is a type of Car.  All Fords have all the properties and functions of a Car but not all Cars have the properties and functions of a Ford.

Comment: As your question is worded it sounds like TabsEdit is a kind of MyViewController.  Is that correct?

Comment: I updated my question accordingly -- but I now get several error messages. First of all: cannot find interface declaration fro MyViewController, but also error messages concerning my init method of TabsEdit: Request for a member 'view' in something not a strucutre or union...

Comment: I like your Ford example. My plan was to have a subclass, i.e. a detail in my ford, like a dashboard, in which I would like to set properties of my ford. So I need access to the entire ford.

Comment: I'll think this through again... I must be off now, but will come back to this tomorrow

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. It sounds like what you are trying to do is just create another custom class (not a subclass) that is a property of your MyViewController and can communicate back and forth with it. Following the anology, a dashboard is a part of a Car but not a Car its self, therefore not a "subclass" of Car but a "property" of Car.

Comment: Exactly! So what I need is a property then... How do I create one? Does this have to do with protocols etc?

Comment: Okay so, what you are looking for is not a subclass but a property for your MyViewController that is a custom class called TabsEdit.  Your initial setup was pretty close then.  The super class for TabsEdit is probably a UIView or UIViewController instead of the MyViewController that we changed it to.

Comment: To send commands from the TabEdit VC to the mainVC you probably want to setup a reference in TabEdit to the mainVC.  It will be a property with the same class as your mainVC and you'll probably call it "delegate".  When you set up the TabEdit from the mainVC you will say myTabEdit.delegate = self. A better way to handle a delegate is to set up a @protocol.  You will have to read up on that.  For the mainVC to talk to the TabEdit it would just refer to the property you already have setup.

Answer (score 2):

[self tabAdd:. .....]

you are derived from VC, so call method directly.

I think you can do a [super tabAdd: .....] as well.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the warning 'subClass' may not respond to -tabAdd: ... Moreover, the app crashed with the following log:  -[TabsEdit tabAdd:inColour:withReference:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b380b0
2011-05-04 21:01:35.626 MoleNotes[78413:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TabsEdit tabAdd:inColour:withReference:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b380b0'

Comment: I just tried it, worked for me. What is the line of code where you are invoking the function look like now? Something may be wrong there.

Comment: could you post the interface for both your VC and the subclass.  I would suspect that you have not correctly setup the subclass.

Comment: Thanks. I've posted an update. I guess the problem is somewhere in how I set this all up.

Comment: @Dancreek: Thanks for your help. I just updated the code ... I guess you're right about me not setting up the subclass correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a method in a super class from a subClass just go:

```
[super methodName];
```

I don't see why you can just go `[self methodName];` either. The subclass should have access to all superclass methods.